# Theoretical way to limit terms in a conlang while also allowing for distinguishing similar concepts/things?

Tags: vocabulary, terminology

I am working on a [conlang](https://github.com/teamtreesurf/tune) (took a little break). I would like to limit the number of "terms" (single words, either 1 or 2 syllables) to less than or equal to 10,000. Given the word-formation rules of the language, there are about 5,000 single syllable words possible, and a few hundred thousand 2-syllable words. But you find some sound better than others, so pick less than that. Maybe up to 20,000 terms...

But the human brain (in my opinion) starts to get lost after 10,000 terms. If you are a native English speaker from the US, just try learning about Chinese cities and historical figures and their works, or Arabic world cities and historical stuff... There are thousands if not tens of thousands of new terms (multi-word terms even) in each category. I don't think it's easy for one human to branch out and learn the details of 20 different cultures like this, that would be over a million terms I would imagine. So hence I think 10,000 would be good enough to learn the entire language.

But then names of things like people or places become more intense.

- Thomas the apostle
- [Jalāl al-Dīn Muḥammad Rūmī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumi)
- United States of America
- [Byzantine Anatolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Anatolia)
- [Isaac Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton)
- [Heraclitus the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heraclius_the_Elder)

You would have to start doing things like:

- Twin the sage of jesus. The twin the sage of the one who was anointed.
- United States of the New World.

So you start getting much longer names, sort of how my limited "popular" view of stereotypical Native American naming might work, with "Wildhorse" or "Dark Cloud" or something like that. I would imagine you would start calling things "Temple Wolf of the Central Desert Pyramid Land" and stuff like that.

Then I imagine a child story.

> Temple wolf of the Great Central Desert Pyramid Land went to eat the red fruit of the big tree. Temple wolf of the Great Central Desert Pyramid Land's friend, Temple Wolf of the Great Western Forest Pyramid Land, lived on the other side of the world. So one day Temple wolf of the Great Central Desert Pyramid Land and Temple Wolf of the Great Western Forest Pyramid Land met up to build the Great Network of the World. First, Temple wolf of the Great Central Desert Pyramid Land did x, then Temple Wolf of the Great Western Forest Pyramid Land did y...

So we have two "people" in the story:

- Temple wolf of the Great Central Desert Pyramid Land
- Temple Wolf of the Great Western Forest Pyramid Land

These are short names even. We might get more complex, with 3 or 4 "of's" and 4-5 nouns per noun phrase.

- The old temple cloud wolf of the black rock area of the great central desert pyramid land.

Part of my question is, how in stories do we distinguish between all the characters? Usually all of the characters have different full names (first and last). But if it's history, many people might have the same name (Pliny the elder, pliny the younger, etc., or king henry VII or whatever). But in historical settings, we don't have that many similar names it seems, unless someone was talking about Bill Clinton and Bill Cosby and Bill Bryson and Bill X in the same story.

But the main part of my question is, **what are the key approaches one can take in a conlang with a limit of 10k terms, for creating sorts of names or identifiers?**

I was first thinking of doing an intro sequence for each new term, but then using a shortened version for each. So our story might become:

> Desert One, Temple wolf of the Great Central Desert Pyramid Land, went to eat the red fruit of the big tree. Desert one's friend, Forest one, Temple Wolf of the Great Western Forest Pyramid Land, lived on the other side of the world. So one day Desert one and Forest one, met up to build the Great Network of the World. First, Desert one did x, then Forest one did y...

That is basically coming up with a "contextual alias" of a longer term, using a shorter term which will be used in the current context/setting of the writing or speech. But you could even just use the alias at first, and introduce them over longer periods of time.

> Desert One went to eat the red fruit of the big tree. Desert one was also known as Temple Wolf, in their home in the Great Central Desert Land with the pyramids. ...

Those "identifying facts" could come at any point in the communication.

I think coming up with these "contextual aliases" would work, and would be better than adding 100k "terms" to the language. Say the comparison is between:

1. 100k terms, combined in 1, 2 or 3 compound terms (like United States of America), giving 1 million complex terms.
2. 10k terms, combined in 1, 2, or 3 compound terms (like Desert one), giving 1 million complex terms. Where these terms are "aliases" to longer more descriptive terms.

I just wonder what are the pros and cons of each approach (these being two approaches to the problem of how to disambiguate things with only 10k terms)?